# DynamoDB result as flat JSON

Tags: node.js, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch items from DynamoDB as a flat JSON.

Here is the Item JSON structure.

```
    {
 "userID": "3201054407a58",
 "createdDate": 1643769000000,
 "modifiedDate": 1643769000000,
 "attributes": {
  "zipCode": "683562",
  "country": "India",
  "deleteFlag": "1"
 }
}
```

Partition key: userID Sort key: createdDate

The query I am using is as given below.

```
let params = {
        "TableName": 'user',
        KeyConditionExpression: "#uid = :id AND createdDate BETWEEN :minDate AND :maxDate",
        FilterExpression: '#attr.#df = :deleteFlag'
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':id': uuid,
            ':minDate': from,
            ':maxDate': to,
            ':deleteFlag': "0"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#uid': 'userID',
            '#attr': 'attributes',
            "#df": "deleteFlag"
        }
    };
```

I would like to get the result as follows

```
{
     "userID": "3201054407a58",
     "createdDate": 1643769000000,
     "modifiedDate": 1643769000000,
      "zipCode": "683562",
      "country": "India",
      "deleteFlag": "1"
 }
```

Please help on this.

Comment: This is not something you can do with DynamoDB, process the result of the Query in javascript.

Comment: What's not working? What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with DynamoDB, this is purely a JavaScript question. You can achieve it after getting your result from the server by creating a new object:

```
function FlattenAttributes(result){
    let flattened = {
        ...result,
        ...result.attributes
    }
    delete flattened.attributes
    return flattened
}
```